# Creating two dependent Dropdown List

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I want to make the third drop down populated based on selection on second drop down refer value from first and second drop down.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#parent_cat").change(function() {
    $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#sub_cat").html(data);
    }); 
});

$("#sub_cat").change(function() {
    $.get('loadsubelement.php?sub_cat=' + $(this).val() + $('#parent_cat').val(), function(data) {
        $("#select_subelement").html(data);
    }); 
});
});
</script>
```

loadsubelement.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];
$sub_cat = $_GET['sub_cat'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM maincategories WHERE categoryID = {$parent_cat}");
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM maincategories WHERE subcategoryID = {$sub_cat}");
echo '<option value="">Please select</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['subcategoryID'].'">' . $row['maincategory_name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: i can make that work with text file am generating value from txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change your query string like this:

```
$.get('loadsubelement.php?sub_cat=' + $(this).val() + 
                          "&parent_cat" + $('#parent_cat').val()
```

You are missing this: `"&parent_cat"` in your second ajax call.

---

Or a better way of doing is to send the an object like this:

```
$("#sub_cat").change(function() {
   var dataString = { 
                 parent_cat : $('#parent_cat').val(),
                 sub_cat : $(this).val()
              };
   if($('#parent_cat').val() !== ""){ // check if value is selected or not i guessed default value as "".
        alert("Please choose the parent value.");
        $('#parent_cat').focus(); // apply focus on the element.
        return false;
   }else{
        $.get('loadsubelement.php', dataString, function(data) {
           $("#select_subelement").html(data);
        });
   } 
});
```

Comment: It's work third drop down it show options,but how can i check first/second drop down value for third drop down?

Comment: @ekalostz you meant if first/second dropdown values are there or not, like some validation before showing the options for third one.

Comment: yes, script in loadsubelement.php how can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery("#office_id").change(function(){
var inputString=jQuery("#office_id").val();
$.post("?r=reports/summary/loademployees/", {office_id: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                    $('#employee_id').fadeIn();
                    $('#employee_id').html(data);
                }
            });
});
});
```

This is a program triggers when when u change a dropdown containing offices having id as *office_id* and load employees (another dropdown box having id *employee_id*) of that office.